# VBA userform dynamic add frames and populate with images

Tags: excel, vba, frame, userform

What i want to do is on some event, let's say combobox change i want to add frames to userform and populate them with images

simplified wersion looks like this

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim newFrame As MSForms.Frame
Dim topPos As Integer
Dim leftPos As Integer
Dim ctl As Control
Dim newImg As MSForms.Image

leftPos = 15
topPos = 15

For i = 1 To 10
    Set newFrame = Me.Controls.Add("forms.frame.1", "Fra" & i)
    With newFrame
        .Top = topPos
        .Left = leftPos
        .Width = 150
        .Height = 20
    End With

    topPos = newFrame.Top + newFrame.Height + 10
Next i

i = 1

For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctl) = "Frame" Then
            Set newImg = Me??????.Controls.Add("forms.image.1", "Img" & i) 
'don't know how to put frame name between me! and  .controls
            With newImg
                .Left = i * 2
                .Width = 30
                .BackColor = RGB(1, 255, 1)
            End With
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
```

don't know how to put frame name between me! and  .controls

Comment: Cast your `ctl` to a `Frame`, I'm pretty sure it has a `Controls` collection of its own.

Comment: Why not add the image in the `newFrame` loop?

Comment: It should be 
`newFrame.Controls.Add("forms.image.1", "Img" & i)`
I tought I've tested it that way but apparently I was wrong

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the "Me"

directly use

```
Set newImg = ctl.controls.add ("Forms.image.1", "Img" & i, true)
```